# Hiking trails that meet specific criteria in Zion National Park (Utah, USA)

Tags: hiking, united-states, national-parks

I'm looking for hiking trails in Zion National Park in Utah, USA.

Here are the criteria:

1. 5-8 miles
2. Moderate skill level (prefer not too easy, but not too strenuous)
3. Prefer no more than 2000 feet of [total elevation gain](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/20485/how-is-elevation-gain-and-change-measured-for-hiking-trails)
4. Great views of the park
5. No amenities required (don't need restrooms or camping facilities)
6. Prefer nothing paved
7. Currently (September 2018) open

I've researched several guide books, and all the trails I've found are either:

1. Currently closed
2. Too short
3. Too easy
4. Too strenuous

If you can include which shuttle stop to use, that would be great as well.

Comment: Note that the currently open requirement might make this question challenging . 
 https://www.nps.gov/zion/planyourvisit/conditions.htm

Comment: @StrongBad Exactly! :)  I'm hoping someone will be able to recommend at least one hike that matches the criteria.  So far, I haven't found anything that's a good fit.

Comment: There aren't that many trails in Zion to begin with (https://www.nps.gov/images/Zion-hike-guide1.jpg), so you may have to string several together to get what you want.